# conditional css is not working to target IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, conditional-statements, css3pie

i'm trying to create border radius for some divs and want them to work on IE too so i'm tryin to use CSS3 PIE. I want to target browsers less then IE9 but it's not working at all

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/main.css"/>
```

the last one is the main stylesheet but when i open ie.css and save any style it doesn't work at all. The page loads without any stylesheet On IE as it's not attached to the html page

Any solution ?

Comment: "it doesn't work at all" isn't very clear. Please state what you expected and what happened.

Comment: code updated please review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the ie.css overwriting the main.css

try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/main.css"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: OK great now the PIE is not working I have this code in ie.css
    .content{
    border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; behavior: url(../../PIE.htc);
    }
the radius is not working ( the path above is from the ie.css to the PIE.htc file )